# Scrolling appbar leaving blank space on top of recyclerview

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi, I have tried to implement the appbar scrolling behavior and it works fine, however, if I scroll when I'm right on the top it seems like there is extra space for one recyclerview row. How do I get rid of the extra space?

activity_main:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/nav_host" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.recyclerviewFragment.RecyclerviewFragment"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerView"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green_300_org"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_a_task"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:tint="@color/black" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding this attribute to the RecyclerView of fragment_recyclerview.xml:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

add it in your activity_main.xml file, and it will work fine.

It will be like:

```
<include
        layout="@layout/nav_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Then you can remove the top padding from your RecyclerView, and you don't need to use CoordinatorLayout in the fragment_recyclerview.xml file as well.

Comment: Such an elegant solution, thanks a lot! I have seen that the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
needs to be a coordinator layout child, but every guide suggested it to be placed in the recyclerview. Is there a real advantage to changing the layout from coordinator to some other layout?

Comment: Just noticed that the FAB seems out of place now. It is working correctly when scrolling down, however, if I try to scroll up, about half of it is hidden behind the android navigation. Is there a fix for that?
If I could just "reverse" the effect:
hide (the whole button, not just the half) on scroll down and show back on scroll up
that would be awesome.

Comment: I didn't notice the FAB. That makes sense, it's moved downward because all of the fragment is moved downward, and it'll return upward when you scroll down, the behavior is done on all of the screen, not just the RecyclerView. 
To fix this, just add the FAB in your activity_main.xml, and hide the FAB in fragments you don't want it to show on. I don't know if there are better practices than this one.
And you can simply add the Coordinator layout, the App Bar and behaviors in your fragment, but it's a bad approach when you need to use it in multiple fragments... you'll duplicate lots of lines.

Comment: And yes, you can hide the FAB when scrolling down with an awesome animation, by adding this attribute to your FAB:
`app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior`
(Make sure that your FAB is inside a Coordinator layout).

Comment: About you first question, choosing the proper layout is depending on your needs, the Coordinator layout is mostly used for these kinds of behaviors, may [this article](https://medium.com/martinomburajr/android-design-coordinator-layout-1-an-introduction-10a1b91ded28) will help. I have read that sometimes choosing unproper layouts affects performance, you can check out [this article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/choosing-the-best-layout-while-designing-your-android-application-560ba2a7f0d4) to get some details.